# set notation for directional derivative: what does this comma mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Under the *proof*, for L,M what does the M stand for? Another function/set or domain? Also under the proof section, can someone give it to me in layman's terms why the first inequality is less than or equal to the second? My first question is the important one, I can probably figure out the second one on my own after I figure out what M refers to, but any inisght is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's another map. They want to prove uniqueness so they take two maps $L$ and $M$ with the given property and they prove that $L=M$.

Comment: It just means that you have two linear maps that have domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}^m$. If you prefer, write it as $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ and $M:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: thanks guys, figured as much after reading it again. Recently introduced to vector calc and somewhat to sets so simple stuff like this isn't always concrete at a first glance.

Comment: tried upvoting both but clicked too many times